# Two swift/ios targets in Xcode project have different options avaiable

Tags: ios, xcode

If you look at the two screenshots, target two has different options available for deployment info / devices - i.e target "2" has the iPhone/iPad buttons under devices

[image]

[image]

The two targets are otherwise to my knowledge configured exactly the same which is why the difference puzzles me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug on this with Apple ages ago, but they pushed it back at me as "expected behavior". It has to do with the version of Xcode in which the project was *originally* created.

Comment: Yes it is Xcode bug but the Info.plist files are correct for both targets and the  app is build and works correct. This is a bug only in displaying properties from Info.plist